# Merge two documents and reshape with arrays

Tags: mongodb

Input data

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
        "ParentNumber" : "12345",
        "ChildNumber" : "A123"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("yyy"),
        "ParentNumber" : "12345",
        "ChildNumber" : "B123"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("zzz"),
        "ParentNumber" : "6789",
        "ChildNumber" : "C123"
    }
]
```

Output Needed

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("aaa"),
        "ParentNumber" : "12345",
        "Children":[
                    { "ChildNumber" : "A123"},
                    { "ChildNumber" : "B123"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("bbb"),
        "ParentNumber" : "6789",
        "Children":[
                    { "ChildNumber" : "C123"}
        ]
    }
    
]
```

I tried the following but can't figure out how to group the parent numbers with children.

```
db.test.aggregate
(
    [
        {
            $project:
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId(),
                "ParentNumber" : "$ParentNumber",
                "Children" : [
                                {
                                    "ChildNumber" : "$ChildNumber"
                                }
                              ]
            }
        }
        
    ]
)
```

I referred to the merge function in mongodb but I can't figure out how to compare one document to another based on a condition and return a result with array.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the desired result. Try this:

```
[{$group: {
  _id: "$ParentNumber",
  children: {
  $push:{'ChildNumber':'$ChildNumber'}
  },

  }}, {$project: {

   "ParentNumber":"$_id",
  children:1
}}]
```

Comment: That worked!. Thanks so much for building on answer if @tahero. Bot answers also helped me understand projections much better,.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mv9D8HDTt1w) 
 PS: it will not show the objectId of the parent

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ParentNumber",
      Children: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      ParentNumber: "$_id",
      Children: {
        "ChildNumber": "$Children.ChildNumber"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. The result is not quite what I need because the  Children array has the ParentNumber property (in addition to the ChildNumber) which should not be there.

Comment: I updated the answer. with $project you can choose which fields to display

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped clarify the basics.